# jQuery If a variable is in array goto "Div" delete all classes in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

What i'm trying to do : Ok I'm trying to build a style switcher here is how it works.

I need help to check condition: If variable is in array goto "Div" delete all classes in array.

### STRUCTURE:

// Radio Group 1 (color)

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="red" >
<input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" checked>
<input type="radio" name="color" id="green">
```

Dynamically store each radio group in array color (all array names are same as radio group name)

```
var color = ['red','blue','green'];
```

// Radio Group 2 (size)

```
<input type="radio" name="size" id="fluid"  checked>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="boxed">
```

Dynamically store array of size from input values

```
var size = ['fluid','boxed'];
```

example html:

```
 <div class" blue fluid"> 
    . . .
 </div>
```

Get the user input

```
 var isChecked = $('#form').on('change',function(){
        isChecked = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

This is the if condition for each radio button where i am stuck now..

// if user select red

//---------------------

```
if( isChecked == 'red'){ 

     // remove any class(blue) from "Div" that match the value in array color[]. 
     // keep classes(fluid) as is if it's not in array color[]. 
     //---------------------------
     // add new class or ID to the DIV.

 }
```

// if user select red

//---------------------

```
if( isChecked == 'red'){ 

     // remove any class(blue) from "Div" that match the value in array color[]. 
     // keep classes(fluid) as is if it's not in array color[]. 
     //---------------------------
     // add new class or ID to the DIV.

 }
```

// if user select blue

//---------------------

```
if( isChecked == 'blue'){ 

     // remove any class(blue) from "Div" that match the value in array color[]. 
     // keep classes(fluid) as is if it's not in array color[]. 
     //---------------------------
     // add new class or ID to the DIV.

 }
```

// if user select green

//---------------------

```
if( isChecked == 'green'){ 

     // remove any class(blue) from "Div" that match the value in array color[]. 
     // keep classes(fluid) as is if it's not in array color[]. 
     //---------------------------
     // add new class or ID to the DIV.

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifically removing the classes set on the `div` element, remove them all using `removeClass()` and re-apply them based on the checked options, something like this:

```js
$('input[name="color"], input[name="size"]').change(function() {
  var $div = $('#foo').removeClass('red blue green fluid boxed');
  var color = $('input[name="color"]:checked').val();
  var size = $('input[name="size"]:checked').val();
  $div.addClass(color + ' ' + size);
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.fluid {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.boxed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> Red
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" checked> Blue
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> Green

<br />

<input type="radio" name="size" value="fluid" checked> Fluid
<input type="radio" name="size" value="boxed"> Boxed

<div id="foo" class="blue fluid"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great technique and thanks for sharing it :)  Some styles are pre applied to the HTML somehow i need them not removed.

Comment: In that case you can just remove the classes you need - see my updated answer using `removeClass('red blue green fluid boxed')`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and helping to solve this issue. I owe you one Rory